# add function is not any new node or display function is showing none but the first node info only

Tags: c, linked-list, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list

`enter code here`In the main function I am calling the add function as well as the display function to see all the present nodes and their stored data into the linked list. But every time it's only showing me the first node value not the other nodes. I can't find any bug into my code. Can any body help...

This is my code:-

```
struct student* add(struct student*);
struct student* search(struct student*);
struct student* modify(struct student*);
void display(struct student* head);
struct student
{
    int roll;
    char name[50];
    float percentage;
    struct student *address;
};
int nodes=0;//nodes variable keeps the data of the total no of nodes present in to the inked list.
int main()
{
    struct student *head;
    int choice;
    char mychoice='y';
    head=NULL;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter 1 to add a node.\nEnter 2 to display all existing record.\nEnter 3 to search a record.\nEnter 4 to modify an existing record.\nEnter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                head=add(head);
                display(head);
                //break;
            case 2:
                display(head);
                break;
            case 3:
                head=search(head);
                break;
            case 4:
                head=modify(head);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Enter any of the correct input.\n");
                break;
        }
        printf("\nDo you want to continue? [Y/N]");
            scanf(" %c",&mychoice);
    }while(mychoice=='y'||mychoice=='Y');
    return 0;
}

struct student* add(struct student* head)
{
    struct student *node,*temp;
    node=(struct student*)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    temp=head;
    printf("Enter the name of the student: ");
    scanf("%s",&(node->name));
    printf("Enter the roll of the student: ");
    scanf("%d",&(node->roll));
    printf("Enter the percentage: ");
    scanf("%f",&(node->percentage));
    node->address=NULL;
    if(head==NULL) // Implies an empty list.
        head=node;
    else
    {
        temp=head;
        while(temp!=NULL)//Traversing to the last node.
            temp=temp->address;
        temp=node;
    }
    nodes++;
    return head;
}

struct student* search(struct student* head)
{
    int m;
    printf("Enter the no of node you wanna search: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    if(m>nodes)
        printf("%dth node does not exist.",m);
    else
        {
            for(i=0;i<m;i++)// Traversing node to node to go to the mth node.
                temp=temp->address;
            printf("\nThe name of the student is: %s\nThe roll no of the student is: %d \nThe percentage of the student is: %5.2f \n\n",temp->name,temp->roll,temp->percentage);            
        }
    return head;
}

struct student* modify(struct student* head)
{
    int m,i;
    struct student *temp;
    temp=head;
    printf("Enter the index no of node you wanna change: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    if(m>nodes)
        printf("%dth node does not exist.",m);
    else
        {
            for(i=0;i<m;i++)// Traversing node to node to go to the mth node.
                temp=temp->address;
            printf("Enter the new name of the student: ");
            scanf("%s",&(temp->name));
            printf("Enter the new roll of the student: ");
            scanf("%d",&(temp->roll));
            printf("Enter the new percentage: ");
            scanf("%f",&(temp->percentage));
        }
    return head;
}

void display(struct student* head)
{
    struct student *temp;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe name of the student is: %s\nThe roll no of the student is: %d \nThe percentage of the student is: %5.2f \n\n",temp->name,temp->roll,temp->percentage);
        temp=temp->address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass your head as a double-pointer from main to add function. Without that any changes made inside it will be only local and will not be reflected back

Comment: What if I declare the head globally and call the functions with no object with void return type....

Comment: Actually I tried that but when I declare head=NULL; globally. It's giving me an error and the program is not executing.

Comment: First, the posted code does not compile!.  The first reason it does not compile is that the `struct student` is being referenced before it is defined.  The second reason it does not compile is it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files. (are you expecting us to guess as to which header files your code actually includes?  Please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug your code

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("\nThe name of the student is: %s\nThe roll no of the student is: %d \nThe percentage of the student is: %5.2f \n\n",temp->name,temp->roll,temp->percentage);`  please break this into short strings that honor the right margin.   You can have the compiler concatenate the strings by surrounding each sub string with double quotes and a newline

Comment: regarding: `            case 1:
                head=add(head);
                display(head);
                //break;
            case 2:
                display(head);`  This results in (when the case is 1) the function: `display( head );` being called twice

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d",&choice);`  When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Those functions return the number of successful input format conversion specifiers.  In this case, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("\nDo you want to continue? [Y/N]");
            scanf(" %c",&mychoice);`  please consistently indent the code

Comment: OT: regarding: `}while(mychoice=='y'||mychoice=='Y');`  Suggest learning about the facility `toupper()` that is found in the `ctype.h` header file

Comment: regarding: `for(i=0;i<m;i++)// Traversing node to node to go to the mth node.`  The variable `i` is not visible in the current scope  Suggest: `for( int i=0; i<m; i++ )// Traversing node to node to go to the mth node.`

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s",&(temp->name));`  1) see my prior comment about the `scanf()` family of functions  2) when using the input format specifiers: '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids an possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: (cont) 3) in C, an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array,  so no `&` needed.  I.E. `if( scanf("%49s",temp->name) ) != 1) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for student name failed\n" ); }`   Of course, when something fails, it is usually necessary to 'cleanup' and call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `node=(struct student*)malloc(sizeof(struct student));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer, so casting is unneeded and just clutters the code.  2) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` `realloc()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` , cleanup and exit.

Comment: regarding: `while(temp!=NULL)//Traversing to the last node.
            temp=temp->address;
        temp=node;`  When `temp` becomes NULL, the loop will be beyond the end of the linked list.   The code needs to 'look ahead' a bit and when the 'next' pointer is NULL, then set the 'next' pointer (in the current node) with the pointer `node`

Comment: If `head` will not change, then why `head=search(head);`?

Comment: in function: `search()`, regarding: `temp=temp->address;`   The variable `temp` is not visible in the current `scope`  And since `head` is not the item of interest, suggest returning `temp` rather than `head`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `add` function your problem is here:

```
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)//Traversing to the last node.
        temp=temp->address;
    temp=node;
```

You never make the currently last node point to the new node. What you do is to assign the new node to `temp` and then return. When you return `temp` goes out of scope and the new node is lost.

To insert a new node, you'll need to update `address` of the last node. In pseudo code you need to do:

```
// Pseudo code to insert a new tail node
current_last_node->address = new_node;
```

Try something like this:

```
    temp=head;
    while(temp->address!=NULL)//Traversing to the last node.
        temp=temp->address;
    temp->address=node;
```

BTW: Calling the pointer to the next element of the list for `address` is not normal. The convention is to use the name `next`.

Two other comments:

1) Since you want to add to the end of the list it's often a good idea to have a `tail` pointer for better performance.

2) You should collect `head`, `nodes` and `tail` into a struct.

Something like:

```
struct student_list
{
    struct student *head;
    struct student *tail;
    int nodes;
};

int main()
{
    struct student_list list = {NULL, NULL, 0};
    add(&list);
    ...
    ...
}
```

Then the `add` function would be:

```
void add(struct student_list* list)
{
    struct student *node;
    node=malloc(sizeof *node);

    // Read data into node

    node->address=NULL;

    if(list->head==NULL) // Implies an empty list.
    {
        list->head=node;
    }
    else
    {
        list->tail->address=node;
    }
    list->tail=node;
    list->nodes++;
}
```

Now there is no loop in the function so adding elements are O(1), i.e. better performance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The way you present two structures in a nested manner is pretty new to me. But still I have understood the idea. The use of no loop concept is cool though when better performance is concern. Can you please explain the last two lines briefly...
Regarding the these two...

else
    {
        list->tail->address=node;
    }
    list->tail=node;
    list->nodes++;


I have understood the if part. That is the first case when there's no node is connected to the list.